# How to use least squares method in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, curve-fitting, least-squares, best-fit-curve

I have 37 linear equations and 36 variables in the form of a matrix equation; A*X=B . The equations don't have an exact answer. I want to use Matlab least square method to find the answers with the least error. I am new to Matlab so any comments will help. Thank you

Comment: X=A\b. As easy as that.check mldivide

Comment: @AnderBiguri, better make this an answer.

Comment: WoW !! That did work ! How about if I want to apply a condition that x(i)>0

Comment: @nasim, I think that makes it a [linear programming](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linear-programming-algorithms.html) problem. Better post another question about that – after doing some research first

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `A` is of full rank, i.e. the columns of `A` are linearly independent, the least-squares solution of an overdetermined system of linear equations

```
A * x = b
```

can be found by inverting the normal equations (see [Linear Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics))):

```
x = inv(A' * A) * A' * b
```

If `A` is not of full rank, `A' * A` is not invertible. Instead, one can use the [pseudoinverse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html) of `A`

```
x = pinv(A) * b
```

or Matlab's [left-division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) operator

```
x = A \ b
```

Both give the same solution, but the left division is more computationally efficient.

The two latter computation methods can also deal with *under*determined systems of linear equations, but they give different solutions in that case: The pseudoinverse gives the solution where `x` has the smallest sum of squares, while the left-division operator gives a solution with as many 0 coefficients as possible.

Comment: I think your `x = inv(A' * A) * A * b` should be `x = inv(A' * A) * A' * b`

Answer (score 5):

The most general way to solve this is to use the pseudoinverse:

```
X = pinv(A) * B;
```

Comment: How about if I want to apply a condition that x(i)>0

Comment: You need the `lsqlin` function for that. I believe the syntax is `x = lsqlin(A,B,[],[],0,inf)`.

Comment: This is numerically inferior to the using `mldivide` (backslash operator) in terms of computational complexity and numerical stability.

Comment: `mldivide` and `pinv` are equivalent for an overdetermined problem like this question, but for an underdetermined problem `pinv` gives the "actual" least-squares solution (the least-energy solution).

Comment: I agree with knedlsepp. Computing a matrix inverse (or pseudoinverse) is almost never a good idea if all you want to do is solve a linear system, both for efficiency and stability reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate x by:

`x = (A'*A)\A'*B`

Comment: I am not sure if this is rigth

Comment: @AnderBiguri You're right. I've just corrected it - though your answer is more compact than mine.

Comment: This expression is only correct when A has full column rank. `pinv` is more general.

Comment: @TamásSzabó, if A is invertible, `(A'*A)*inv(A)` gives the same solution as `pinv` and the backslash. If A is not invertible, your equation using the backslash still works, but is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @rlbond, it also works if A is not of full rank, because Tamás is using the backslash operator

Comment: How about if I want to apply a condition that x(i)>0

Comment: @nasim you can't pose constraints on the solution when your problem is formulated as an equation. If your problem is an inequality, take a look at matlab's `linprog` function

Comment: @TamásSzabó, I have to correct myself, again. I often get confused by which way the backslash operator goes.

Comment: @A.Donda - Just remember where the slash is learning towards.  Wherever it's leaning, that's where the inverse is being taken.... so `A\b` with the ` \ ` leaning towards the `A` means `inv(A)*b` (assuming full rank) and doing `A/b` means `A*inv(b)` (also assuming full rank).  I get confused all the time and I finally nailed it by just looking at the direction of where the slash is leaning.