# Matlab \ operator and OLS solution

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB the OLS solution to the $y = X \beta + \epsilon$ can be calculated by

(X'*X) \ (X'*y)

but it seems

X \ y is also a least squares solution.

What is the difference between the two? If any? Basically is there a point to use the first option as it is likely to be slower?

Comment: Please consult the duplicate.  In general, provided that `X` is full rank, they will both provide the same solution.  There will be differences for underdetermined systems.  It is highly recommended you simply use `X \ y` as the `mrdivide` operator will internally determine the most stable way to compute the solution to the system.

Comment: I disagree.  Look at Tomas's answer.  It exactly answers what you're looking for.  If there are more people that disagree, then I'll consider reopening it but I'll leave it as is.

Comment: @rayryeng OK. Your comment is an answer. The other question doesn't explain why there is no point to use the first option.

Comment: Please consult Tomas's answer in the duplicate and look at the comments stream.  It will show you what you're looking for.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30334802/3250829

Comment: @rayryeng For full rank is there a difference in terms of performance between two options?

Comment: Ah, well in that case no.  The post-multiplication with `X'` is done internally within the ` \ ` operator.  You would basically be cutting the middle man away if you did that yourself prior to using ` \ ` .  I'd like to direct you to this useful question and answer that give a flowchart on what ` \ ` is doing internally... that is... deciding which method to use for solving the system: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553210/how-to-implement-matlabs-mldivide-a-k-a-the-backslash-operator